# How to do git log --no-walk --tags in JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I would like to use `LogCommand` from JGit to execute the mentioned command. How can I write the custom filter which can do the job? I have done something like:

```java
RevFilter revFilter = new RevFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean include(RevWalk revWalk, RevCommit revCommit) throws StopWalkException, MissingObjectException, IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException {
    if (revCommit.getParentCount() > 0) { // do not traverse parent(s) }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public RevFilter clone() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the HEAD commits of all tags in a repository, you can use JGit to return all tags and then resolve the commit of each tag.

The `RefDatabase` can be queried to return all tags:

```java
Map<String, Ref> allTags repository.getRefDatabase().getRefs("refs/tags/");
```

Then use a `RevWalk` to resolve each tag ref:

```java
for (Ref tagRef : allTags.values()) {
  try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
    RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(tagRef.getObjectId();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i have to append some more arguments e.g. --decorate=full --topo-order

Comment: You'll likely have to implement this yourself. JGit is not a ready-to-use git command line tool, but an API to access git repositories. The `LogCommand` is far from supporting what `git log` does. See here for all that is supported: https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.java